# Fetching route parameters in Node js

Tags: javascript

I'm building a REST api server in Node js. Let's say I have an Api - `http://localhost:3000/api/employee/:employeeId`. And I want to fetch the employeeId parameter without using any framework such as Express js. If possible what would be a better approach ?

Comment: what about a string split? `let url = localhost:3000/api/employee/:employeeId, urlSegments = url.split('/');` and then just refer to `urlSegments[3]` for that last item in the array of url segments.

Comment: Not sure why you don't want to use express, but looking at https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html may give you some hints

Comment: ExpressJS uses [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp) under the hood for its routing. You could use that directly.

Comment: RE: `If possible what would be a better approach?` Express has become the defacto standard web framework for Node.js. There isn't a better approach. Anything else would be less... battle tested.

Answer (score 0):

**If you Need the Employee Id from Url So You can use this - **

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('http://localhost:3000/api/employee/:employeeId',getUserById);

getUserById(req, res) {

```
   console.log('---EmployeeId ----',req.params.employeeId);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's a vanilla js function to get the url segments

```
function UrlSegments() {
    // Change this to the correct url if its not 
    // the url that you want to process
    // You can also do window.location.pathname to process
    // the current path.
    let urlSegments: string[] = /api/employee/:employeeId

    // Remove the empty string before the first '/'
    if (urlSegments.shift() === "")
        urlSegments.slice(1, -1);
    // Remove the empty string after the last '/'
    if (urlSegments.slice(-1)[0] === "")
        urlSegments.splice(-1, 1);

    return urlSegments;
}   

string employeeId = UrlSegments()[2];
```